# Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Observable<{}>

Tags: angular

Here is the code please help me to solve this error...

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

export class WebService {
  MAIN_URL='....';
  private myStore = [];
  private mySubject = new Subject();
  my = this.mySubject.asObservable();
  ....
 }
```

My Component code

```
<div *ngFor="let my of webService.my | async">
```

Comment: ngFor works on array

Comment: Thanks... Solved...